# munin on Centos

Tags: apache, centos, munin

I have installed Munin on Centos 6.2 and successfully configured and launched it.
The only problem is that in the var/www/html/munin folder, I only have :

```
/static
/cgi
```

There is not index.html or anything else so Munin cannot function properly ... There are some accessory files in /static

My munin node **configuration** is :

```
#
# Example config-file for munin-node
#

log_level 4
log_file /var/log/munin/munin-node.log
pid_file /var/run/munin/munin-node.pid

background 1
setsid 1

user root
group root


# Regexps for files to ignore
ignore_file [\#~]$
ignore_file DEADJOE$
ignore_file \.bak$
ignore_file %$
ignore_file \.dpkg-(tmp|new|old|dist)$
ignore_file \.rpm(save|new)$
ignore_file \.pod$

# Set this if the client doesn't report the correct hostname when
# telnetting to localhost, port 4949
#
host_name my.host.is

# A list of addresses that are allowed to connect.  This must be a
# regular expression, since Net::Server does not understand CIDR-style
# network notation unless the perl module Net::CIDR is installed.  You
# may repeat the allow line as many times as you'd like

allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$
allow 192.168.15.173
allow my.host.is

# If you have installed the Net::CIDR perl module, you can use one or more
# cidr_allow and cidr_deny address/mask patterns.  A connecting client must
# match any cidr_allow, and not match any cidr_deny.  Note that a netmask
# *must* be provided, even if it's /32
#
# Example:
#
# cidr_allow 127.0.0.1/32
# cidr_allow 192.0.2.0/24
# cidr_deny  192.0.2.42/32

# Which address to bind to;
host *
#host 127.0.0.1

# And which port
port 4949
```

**Owner** and Group on the /var/www/html/munin folder is munin

When going to the /munin url, apache thrown the following error :

```
Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/munin/
```

Any clue on what happened and how I could fix it ?

Comment: You munini works or not with this empty folder?

Comment: what about your munin-node status? what about owner of this folder? please add your munin-node configuration,

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, until/unless you do one of the following:

- enable cgi content generation (the default for version 2.x)
- ensure that munin-cron is invoking munin-html to generate the content (the default for version 1.4.x)

What did you set 'graph_strategy' to in your munin.conf ?